# Multiple ports and mount points in AWS ECS Fargate Task Definition using Ansible

Tags: ansible, amazon-ecs, ansible-inventory, aws-fargate

I went through the documentation provided here

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/aws/ecs_taskdefinition_module.html

It gives me nice examples of setting of Fargate task definition. However it showcases example with only one port mapping and  there is no mount point shown  here.
I want to dynamically add port mappings ( depending on my app) and volume/mount points

For that I am defining my host_var for app as below ( there can be many such apps with different mount points and ports)

```
---
task_count: 4
task_cpu: 1028
task_memory: 2056
app_port: 8080
```

My Task definition yaml file looks like below

```
    - name: Create/Update Task Definition
      ecs_taskdefinition:
        aws_access_key: "{{....}}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{....}}"
        security_token: "{{....}}"
        region: "{{....}}"
        launch_type: FARGATE
        network_mode: awsvpc
        execution_role_arn: "{{ ... }}"
        task_role_arn: "{{ ...}}"
        containers:
          - name: "{{...}}"
            environment: "{{...}}"
            essential: true
            image: "{{ ....}}"
            logConfiguration: "{{....}}"
            portMappings:
              - containerPort: "{{app_port}}"
                hostPort: "{{app_port}}"

        cpu: "{{task_cpu}}"
        memory: "{{task_memory}}"
        state: present
```

I am able to create/update the task definition.

**New requirements are that**

1. Instead of one port, now we can have multiple(or none) port mappings.
2. We will have multiple (or none)  mount points  and volumes as well

Here is what I think the modified ansible host_var should look like below for ports
[container_port1:host_port1, container_port2:host_port2, container_port3:host_port3]

```
task_count: 4
task_cpu: 1028
task_memory: 2056
#[container_port1:host_port1, container_port2:host_port2, container_port3:host_port3]
app_ports: [8080:80, 8081:8081, 5703:5703]
```

I am  not sure what to do in ansible playbook to run through this list of ports.

Another part of the problem is that, although I was able to achieve creating volume and mouting in container thorough aws console, I was not able to do same using ansible.

here is the snippet of json for the AWS fargate looks like ( for volume part). There can be many such mounts depending on the application. I want to achieve that dynamically by defining mount points and volumes in host_vars

```
-
-
-

      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "readOnly": null,
          "containerPath": "/mnt/downloads",
          "sourceVolume": "downloads"
        }
-
-
-
-
-
-
"volumes": [
    {
      "efsVolumeConfiguration": {
        "transitEncryptionPort": ENABLED,
        "fileSystemId": "fs-ecdg222d",
        "authorizationConfig": {
          "iam": "ENABLED",
          "accessPointId": null
        },
        "transitEncryption": "ENABLED",
        "rootDirectory": "/vol/downloads"
      },
      "name": "downloads",
      "host": null,
      "dockerVolumeConfiguration": null
    }
```

I am not sure how to do that.
Official documentation offers very little help.